# Change visibility and opacity to div item when onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm developing a website and I want to show a div after a button is clicked. Right now, I'm able to hide and show when a button is clicked using:

```
<button type="submit" id="appendData" onclick="viewDetail()">View Detail</button>

<div id="right" style="display:none">
            <button type="submit" id="saveDetail" onclick="saveDetail()">Save details</button>
        </div>

<script>
    function viewDetail(){
        document.getElementById('right').style.display = "inline-block";
    }
    function saveDetail(){
        document.getElementById('right').style.display = "none";
    }

</script>
```

Now, this it's ok, but since this is a webapp that it's supossed to be deployed to all my coworkers, I want it to look good and be nice and smooth to use, so, I want to add a transition to the div. I've googled a lot, and I've seen some examples that worked, but not the way I want to. I want to change it's visibility and opacity or, grow from a corner like android material design does.

Right now, In my css file, I've defined this:

```
#right {
    width: 40%;
    position: relative;
}
.right {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: visibility 1s, opacity 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: visibility 1s, opacity 1s linear;
    -o-transition: visibility 1s, opacity 1s linear;
    transition: visibility 1s, opacity 1s linear;
}
.right-visible {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

And, In my html code:

```
<div id="right" style="display:none" class="right" >
            <button type="submit" id="saveDetail" onclick="saveDetail()">Save details</button>
```

and to handle the click on the button:

```
$(function() {
    $("#viewDetail").click(function() {
        $(".right").toggleClass("right-visible");
    });
});
```

but, however, It's not getting into the function to do the toggleClass command. I've also tried:

```
function saveDetail(){
    $(".right").toggleClass("right");
}
function viewDetail(){
    $(".right").toggleClass("right-visible");
}
```

but this is not working as well. I know that I'm missing something, but I can't find what it is. Will appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you checked your browser console for errors? If not then I recommend you check there first.

Comment: Yes, there is no errors at the browser console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check this. I have changed `button` id in html and remove inline css.

```js
$(function() {
    $("#viewDetail").click(function() {
        $(".right").toggleClass("right-visible");
    });
     $("#saveDetail").click(function() {
        $(".right").removeClass("right-visible");
    });
});
```

```css
#right {
    width: 40%;
    position: relative;
    border:1px solid #000;
    height:50px;
}
.right {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: visibility 1s, opacity 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: visibility 1s, opacity 1s linear;
    -o-transition: visibility 1s, opacity 1s linear;
    transition: visibility 1s, opacity 1s linear;
}
.right-visible{
    opacity:1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="right" class="right" >
  <button type="submit" id="saveDetail">Save details</button>
</div>
<button type="submit" id="viewDetail">View details</button>
```

Comment: Details of your changes and the reasons for them seem to be missing from your answer...

Comment: It was a problem with one ID that I've changed. Thanks!

Comment: So, I'm using a viewDetail to show the div using your answer, and that works flawlessly. Inside the div right, there is another button with id="saveDetail" and when the user clicks on it, I want to take it back to original. So, I've created a right-invisible class on the css file, and duplicated the code and changed bits to adjust it. the function it's triggering when clicking, but not hiding it. Would you update your answer to point that out, please?

Comment: Also, afer 1 iteration, it doesn't work anymore. the output it's showing on the console, but no effect is made on the display.